# C++ How to set a pointer of type std::vector<Derived*> to object of type std::vector<Base*>

Tags: c++, polymorphism, static-cast

The Background:

I'm building a physics engine in C++ that computes the gravitational evolution of an n-body system in Cartesian space and then translates that into any of a predefined set of coordinate systems. Eventually the goal is the make the starting coordinate system arbitrary (calculate in coordinate system 'n' instead of only Cartesian), but that is a distant goal.

The Problem:

Because the coordinate system is supposed to be interchangeable, I have made the Cartesian coordinate system extend a base coordinate system:

```
class CoordMember {
}

class CoordState {
   public:
      /* methods to operate on members */

   protected:
      std::vector<CoordMember*> members;
}

class Particle : public CoordMember {
}

class CartState : public CoordState {
}
```

The error arises when trying to create a pointer of type `std::vector<Particle*>` which points to the members object of type `std::vector<CoordMember*>`:

```
CartState* state = new CartState(/* initialization vars */);
std::vector<Particle*>* parts = static_cast< std::vector<Particle*>* >(&state->members);
```

Compiler errors are:

```
error: static_cast from 'std::vector<CoordMember *> *' to 'std::vector<Particle *> *' is not allowed
error: no viable overloaded '='
```

I know for a fact at this point that the data in `state->members` are all of type `Particle*`. What I don't know is what has to be done to make this cast possible. Any ideas?

tl;dr:

```
std::vector<Derived*>* ptr = static_cast< std::vector<Base*>* >(&object);
static_cast from 'std::vector<Derived*>*' to 'std::vector<Base*>*' is not allowed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast doesn't work because the `vector`s are **completely unrelated**. You'll have to cast each individual object in the vector.

Comment: How should I do this? I don't want to copy the contents of the members vector to a vector of a different type (as I want to operate on the original members function), I just want to treat the vector as a vector of the derived type for a few function calls.

Comment: @chpatton013 you can't, and you don't have to copy it. Just cast elements from inside the vector to the type you need before you use them.

Comment: As, I assume, you'll be using them polymophically, the solution is to maintain a `vector<Base *>` in the first place.   be sure to define a virtual destructor for class `Base`.